# How to change alias name based on form control?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In Access 365, I have an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT tblA.Q_4Response AS [2020YTD Q_4Response]
```

Every year I will have to change that alias, but I'd rather have the user do it on the dashboard. I tried something like this:

```
SELECT tblA.Q_4Response AS [Forms]![frmDashboard]![txtReportYear] & [YTD Q_4Response]
```

but that gives the error "SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. Field and table names must be static.

You can open the QueryDef object and adjust its SQL property:

```
NewSql = "SELECT tblA.Q_4Response AS [" & [Forms]![frmDashboard]![txtReportYear] & "YTD Q_4Response] From YourTable"

YourQuery.SQL = NewSql
```

Comment: So I'd have to use VBA?

Comment: Yes, in one way or another.